# How do requests from clients to an API get routed through the gateway hosted on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I'm not entirely new to MS Azure, but I am new to its API Management Service.  I am trying to get an understanding of how the routing works between the client, the APIMS, and the backend APIs, but somehow can't seem to find what I'm looking for within Microsoft's documentation.

So here's what we have and what I understand:
We have multiple APIs that we host on Azure as App Services.  And those APIs are added to the APIMS, which we are using as a gateway.  The APIMS's Inbound policies on each API specifies the backend service as that App.  But that's all I know.

So when a client, say an application running on someone's computer, sends a request to one of those APIs, how does its request URL end up routing through the gateway?  And how does that all relate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the request URL is made up as follows:

**[name of your APIM service].azure-api.net/[name of api]/[api method]/[querystring]**

example:

https://myapimanager.azure-api.net/myapi/getstudent?id=1
https://myapimanager.azure-api.net/myotherapi/getsomethingelse?name=bubbles